# Swagger Codegen Java RequestBody Name

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I am using the swagger-codegen Spring generator to generate the API classes using a YAML API definition. I am describing post request with multiple parameters in the body like this:

```
paths:
  /api/test:
    post:
      ...
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              properties:
                firstName:
                  type: string
                lastName:
                  type: string
```

This generates a method in the ApiDelegate with the signature `ResponseEntity test(Body body)`. **However, when describing multiple post methods like this, the subsequent generated signatures have parameters of type `Body1`, `Body2`, ... .** With Swagger 2.0, it was possible to name the RequestBodies. Can I do something similar with V3?

Thanks for your help!
Kind regards

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Facing the same issue were my request class is just named [endpoint]Body. Would like to have the word request in there at least.

Comment: @Skillzore An OpenAPI-Generator contributor reached out to me and told me that it is possible when switching from swagger-codegen to OpenAPI-Generator: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/migration-from-swagger-codegen.md#body-parameter-name

Comment: @TimoZikeli, then I need to edit the specification file with `x-codegen-request-body-name` for every endpoint? I hoped for an `option` during generation...